# Are S3 Kedro datasets thread-safe?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, kedro

`CSVS3DataSet`/`HDFS3DataSet`/`HDFS3DataSet` use `boto3`, which is known to be not thread-safe https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html?highlight=multithreading#multithreading-multiprocessing

Is it OK to use these datasets with the ParallelRunner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Kedro` uses `s3fs`, which uses `boto3` library to access S3. `Boto3` is not thread-safe indeed, but only if you are trying to reuse the same Session object.

All `Kedro` S3 datasets maintain separate instances of `S3FileSystem`, which means separate boto sessions, so it's safe.

It's probably not great in terms of performance, and if you work with hundreds of S3 data sets in parallel, or thousands of small S3 datasets sequentially - the pipeline might run quite long and even fail on connection errors, but you are totally safe with a few dozens of them.